# Ubuntu 20.04, causes random freezing/crashes with Nvidia GPU (BUG: Bad page state in process...)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, freeze

Ubuntu 20.04 freezes/crashes randomly - 20 mins to ~3 hrs, current NVIDIA driver - 535.54.03 (No freezing if I'm not using GPU)

I have tried different Nvidia drivers 530.30.02, 525.85 also Ubuntu 22.04.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           62Gi       6.1Gi       413Mi       1.0Gi        55Gi        54Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       1.4Gi       597Mi
```

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

```
sudo lshw -C memory
```

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 0603
       date: 09/08/2022
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 768KiB
       capacity: 768KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: e
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 64MiB
       capacity: 64MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 11
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 64GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 4800 MHz (0.2 ns)
          product: F5-5600J3636D32G
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 505MHz (2.0ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 4800 MHz (0.2 ns)
          product: F5-5600J3636D32G
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 505MHz (2.0ns)
```

[JournalCTL](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rashmibanthia/8caf66937f22937cf607023dd7c02bb7/raw/5d339415ffc3f22e184e1c1c6e8f12a1078e8774/journalctl) - This is a large file, search for "BUG: Bad page state in process"

[dmesg](https://gist.github.com/rashmibanthia/1d0bcd1d9026dad951381b3c4ae3b747)

I also tried `memtester` - it didn't return any errors

I have been struggling with this for more than a week, I would really appreciate any suggestions/help. I have also gone through many similar questions on this forum.